# Cannot get background image to work with React-Native and NativeBase

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am trying to use NativeBase with ReactNative and have a picture as the background.  I've been googling for a while and here is the code I've come up with:

```
export default class WelcomeScreen extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <Container>
                <Header>
                    <Button transparent>
                        <Icon name='ios-arrow-back' />
                    </Button>
                </Header>
                <Content>
                    <Image source={require('../images/telula_upclose.jpeg')} style={styles.backgroundImage} />
                    <Text>Do you ever feel like you dont have a partner</Text>
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

let styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }
});
```

The problem is that this stretches the image a great deal so that it's unrecognizable in the simulator.  Here's a picture of what's in the simulator compared to the actual image:

[image: Simulator Image]

and here's the actual image:

[image: Actual Picture]

How do I fix this?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html resizeMode PropTypes.oneOf(['cover', 'contain', 'stretch', 'repeat', 'center'])  probably you are looking for 'contain'

Comment: I am Sanket from NativeBase team. Let me re-create this at my end. I will keep you posted on this.

Answer (score 5):

I have two solutions for this:

1. The [NativeBase Content](http://nativebase.io/docs/v0.5.7/components#content) component is a wrapper of [React Native ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html).
   Image when used with ScrollView makes it necessary to include height and width of image.
2. If you want to exclude mentioning dimensions for image, use `View` in place of `Content`.

```
<View>
  <Image
     source={testImage}
     style={{ flex: 1, height: null, width: null, resizeMode: 'cover' }}
  />
  <Text>Do you ever feel like you dont have a partner</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the HEIGHT and WIDTH of the image to get it into view port, for this you can use the `Dimensions` API of react-native. For more detail read this [react-native doc for Dimensions API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html).

```
import { Text, View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

export default class WelcomeScreen extends Component {
render(){
    let {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
    return (
        <Container>
            <Header>
                <Button transparent>
                    <Icon name='ios-arrow-back' />
                </Button>
            </Header>
            <Content>
                <Image source={require('../images/telula_upclose.jpeg')}  
                   style={[styles.backgroundImage, {height:height, width: width}]} />
                <Text>Do you ever feel like you dont have a partner</Text>
            </Content>
        </Container>
    );
  }
}

let styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundImage: {
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor:'transparent',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
 }
});
```

and if you want your text over the background image then wrap it within `<Image>` component.

```
<Image>
   <View>
     <Text>Hello!! </Text>
   </View>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a component that does it:

```
import {
  Dimensions,
  Image,
} from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const BackgroundImage = (props) => {
  const window = Dimensions.get('window')
  const height = props.height || window.height
  const width = window.width
  const resizeMode = props.resizeMode || 'cover' // cover
  return (
    <Image
      style={[props.styles, {height: height - props.headerSize, width: null, resizeMode: resizeMode }]}
      opacity={1}
      source={props.uri ? {uri: props.uri} : props.source}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Image>
  )
}

export default BackgroundImage
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex: 1` styling on an `<Image>` element to have it fill the whole screen. You can then use one of the Image resize modes to have the image completely fill the element:

```
<Image style={style.backgroundImage} source={require('../../assets/images/bg.png')}  />
```

**Component**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';

class ReactBGImg extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Image style={style.backgroundImage} source={require('../../assets/images/bg.png')}  />
            <View style={style.backgroundTransperant}>
                <Text>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla in tristique ligula, quis tristique justo. Cras dictum est libero, eget pretium nunc vestibulum sit amet.
                </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    backgroundImage: {
        flex: 1,
        resizeMode: 'cover',
        position: 'absolute',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    }
    backgroundTransperant: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    }
});
```

Hope it should helpful for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dimension for get a size screen and resize a image:

1- import Dimension:

```
import { View, Text, Dimensions } from 'react-native'
```

2- in your component get hardware size in object window

```
const window = Dimensions.get('window');
```

3- added a dimention your Image

```
<Image
     style={{width: window.width, height: window.height}}
     source={require('../images/telula_upclose.jpeg')}
/>
```

Warning: Your image may be deform. Use 'resizeMode' props in your Image

You can look this for more information: [documentation for Image and resizeMode](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html)

Comment: That seems very complicated for such basic functionality?  I have to imagine there's a built-in way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the react-native [ImageBackground](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/imagebackground) component designed exactly for rendering background images